# Tail multiple directories

Tags: bash, directory, ls, tail, xargs

How do I print only the last (n) file(s) inside nested directories matching a certain pattern?

Doing

```
ls -l dir*/history/ | tail
```

gives only the content of the last directory.

I suspect it has to do with `xargs` but can't really figure out how.

Comment: Do you want to print 10 files per subdirectory, or overall?

Comment: It would help to know what type of *"certain pattern"* you need to find to know whether *globbing* or *regex matching* is needed.

Comment: I think I understood your need finally. Try the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly, use the loop:

```
for d in dir*/history/; do
    ls -l "$d" | tail
done
```

But, for more advanced directory "filtering" (and processing) than this, `find` might come in handy.

Comment: Put it all on one line, e.g. `for d in dir*; do ls -l "$d" | tail; done`

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
find . -type d -name "dir*" | while read dir; do find "$dir" | tail -n 5; done
```

Not very laconic, but if you need to match all the levels of nested directories and pick N files from each subdirectory...
Also add 2>/dev/null before each pipe to supress 'permission denied' messages. Or use sudo.
An equivalent with process substitution, if you need to change global variables within the while loop:

```
while read dir; do find "$dir" | tail -n 5; done < <(find . -type d -name "dir*")
```

Comment: Adding a `-name "pattern"` would help the answer match the updated question a bit better. You will also need to add a `sort` as `find` doesn't preserve canonical sort order.

Comment: I edited the post to add that my dir pattern is nested. Your example doesn't really work (not sure it's for that).

Comment: You are right, edited.
Somebody managed to vote me down, though :)

Comment: It prints only last 10 files overall, not per directory. And you don't need `grep` if you use `-name` filter in `find`.

Comment: Well, he didn't say per directory.
-name is wrong, because it matches file names, not directory's along the path. -path is wrong too, as it matches both file names and directory names along the path.

Comment: Try `find . -type f -path './dir*/history/*'`.

Comment: I can't pick N files from each directory with that.

Comment: I cannot make it to work; it's printing other stuff. Anyway if that wasn't clear I should repeat that I don't want to tail the overall ls but to tail each directory individually...

Comment: It perfectly works for me, just be careful with patterns.

Comment: Also if you have a different nested pattern it could be wrongly included. Like if you would have `nogo/dir1/history` that one would still be considered. Anyway I guess the loop could be wrapped in a function and aliased. Thanks for spending some time